# SageMath: "name 'type_check' is not defined"

Tags: numpy, sage

I am brand new to SageMath and have come across the following error message:

```
sage: diagonal_matrix([2, 1.3, 5])                                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-97b135e19796> in <module>
----> 1 diagonal_matrix([Integer(2), RealNumber('1.3'), Integer(5)])

~/Desktop/SageMath/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sage/matrix/special.py in diagonal_matrix(arg0, arg1, arg2, sparse)
    852 
    853     # sanity check for entries
--> 854     from numpy import ndarray
    855     if not isinstance(entries, (list, tuple, ndarray)):
    856         entries = list(entries)

~/Desktop/SageMath/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py in <module>
    146     from .core import *
    147     from . import compat
--> 148     from . import lib
    149     # NOTE: to be revisited following future namespace cleanup.
    150     # See gh-14454 and gh-15672 for discussion.

~/Desktop/SageMath/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py in <module>
     42 
     43 __all__ = ['emath', 'math', 'tracemalloc_domain', 'Arrayterator']
---> 44 __all__ += type_check.__all__
     45 __all__ += index_tricks.__all__
     46 __all__ += function_base.__all__

NameError: name 'type_check' is not defined
```

This input comes directly from [the documentation](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/matrices/sage/matrix/special.html#sage.matrix.special.diagonal_matrix), yet I am lost as to why my out-of-the-box Sage installation is throwing this error. Other possibly relevant information: I am running Sage through the Terminal on a Mac. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It happened to me once in jupyter lab - after interrupting one of the cells execution it declined to import numpy. Kernal restart was the solution. Did you interrupt SageMath's command before it happened?